# Extension manager is not working in typo3 version 6.0

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

i am on the latest version of typo3 (version 6.0) , In that all working fine except the typo3 extension manager , when i take the extension manager from the admin panel all i got the message is `"The connection was reset"` as we get the message like when there is no internet connection ,
So is there need the internet connection to work the extension manager ?? I didnt search for any new extensions from the repository , But it should load the base page of the extension manager that contains all the default extensions used in typo3 right ?

Comment: It does try to fetch the extensions if the last update time is empty.

Comment: Long shot: Do you use xampp? If so, increase the stack size, e.g. with `ThreadStackSize 8388608`.

Comment: @ pgampe : but the page should load right , its not showing anything ,only the  "The connection was reset" as we get when there is no internet connection

Comment: @Jost : NO i use wamp , how can i  increase the stack size in wamp ??

Comment: Add the line from above to your httpd.conf.

Comment: @jost: I cant see any line related to ThreadStackSize in my httpd.conf in wamp ,its wrong

Comment: There is no line with ThreadStackSize, because the Windows default value is used (1 MB). Just add a new line containing `ThreadStackSize 8388608`, setting the Stack size to 8MB, the Linux default.

Comment: OKay , thank you jost ,let me check that

Comment: Wow ! worked like a magic , Thank you very much

Answer (score 10):

The reason could be that xampp has a too small default stack size, leading to a stack overflow and connection reset.

Could you try to add "ThreadStackSize 8388608" to your httpd.conf?

Answer (score -1):

Just to help a ittle bit, I'll help translate the answer (Is spanish, in case anyone wants to know)

Thanks a lot for the solution, it worked for me on Xampp!, now I can use typo3 extension manager, you should take in consideration the follow procedure too: Note: To be able to use extension manager is necesarry to activate the option [curlUse] from the menu "Tools--> All configuration", the password configured during typo3 install will be required again. Besides, you need to have the curl php library in your system, on Debian/Ubuntu